# Custom JTextArea wrap word style

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap, jtextarea

I've got a JTextArea with `setLineWrap(true)` and (for now) `setWrapStyleWord(true)`.

The text which is contained in that textArea contains almost no white space, and so the wrapping never occurs. But the text is semi-colon separated. And so I'd like to achieve a wrap style at the ";" instead of at the " ".

With the following text:

```
hello;world;foo;bar;I am the Wizard;of;Oz
```

Wrapping like

```
hello;world;foo;bar;
I am the Wizard;
of;Oz
```

Instead of (with `setWrapStyleWord(true)`)

```
hello;world;foo;bar;I 
am the Wizard;of;Oz
```

or

Instead of (with `setWrapStyleWord(false)`)

```
hello;world;foo;bar;I a
m the Wizard;of;Oz
```

Any idea on how to realize this ?

Comment: Why is your text semicolon separated?  Is displaying the semicolons important?  Since your text doesn't consist of words, `setWrapStyleWord(false)` is probably your best choice.

Comment: The texts is actually a set of semicolon-separated tags. So the semicolons are mandatory. I was hoping to find a way to tweak/hack the word wrapping style.

Comment: Add a space after the semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to tweak the ComponentUI used by the JTextArea. See this [discussion](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1375759/where-in-the-jtextarea-code-is-line-word-wrapping-handled).

One could create directly a new ComponentUI and assign it to the JTextArea, but I recommend to create a new JTextArea subclass handling all this under the radar.

### The Component

```
package com.zparkingb.swing;

import com.zparkingb.swing.ui.SeparatedTextAreaUI;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class ZSeparatedTextArea extends JTextArea {

    private final Character wordSeparator;
    
    private static final String uiClassID = "SeparatedTextAreaUI";

    public ZSeparatedTextArea(Character separator) {
        super();
        this.wordSeparator = separator;
    }

    public ZSeparatedTextArea(Character separator, String text) {
        super(text);
        this.wordSeparator = separator;
    }

    public ZSeparatedTextArea(Character separator, int rows, int columns) {
        super(rows, columns);
        this.wordSeparator = separator;
    }

    public ZSeparatedTextArea(Character separator, String text, int rows, int columns) {
        super(text, rows, columns);
        this.wordSeparator = separator;
    }

    public ZSeparatedTextArea(Character separator, Document doc) {
        super(doc);
        this.wordSeparator = separator;
    }

    public ZSeparatedTextArea(Character separator, Document doc, String text, int rows, int columns) {
        super(doc, text, rows, columns);
        this.wordSeparator = separator;
    }

    public Character getWordSeparator() {
        return wordSeparator;
    }
    
    public void setUI(SeparatedTextAreaUI ui) {
        super.setUI(ui);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUI() {
        if (UIManager.get(getUIClassID()) != null) {
            SeparatedTextAreaUI ui = (SeparatedTextAreaUI) UIManager.getUI(this);
            setUI(ui);
        }
        else {
            setUI(new SeparatedTextAreaUI());
        }
    }

    public SeparatedTextAreaUI getUI() {
        return (SeparatedTextAreaUI) ui;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUIClassID() {
        return uiClassID;
    }
}
```

### The ComponentUI

```
package com.zparkingb.swing.ui;

import com.zparkingb.swing.ZSeparatedTextArea;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.View;

public class SeparatedTextAreaUI extends BasicTextAreaUI {

    private ZSeparatedTextArea textArea = null;

    /**
     * Creates the view for an element. Returns a SeparatedWrappedPlainView (or WrappedPlainView/PlainView if no wordSeparator is provided)
     *
     * @param elem the element
     *
     * @return the view
     */
    public View create(Element elem) {
        if (textArea.getWordSeparator() == null)
            return super.create(elem);
        View v = new SeparatedWrappedPlainView(textArea.getWordSeparator(), elem);
        return v;
    }

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new SeparatedTextAreaUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        textArea = (ZSeparatedTextArea) c;
        super.installUI(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
        super.uninstallUI(c);
        textArea = null;
    }

}
```

### The View

This one is more tricky. As some information required to do the word wrapping are private in `SeparatedWrappedPlainView` they have been duplicated (e.g. `metrics`)

```
package com.zparkingb.swing.ui;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.Segment;
import javax.swing.text.TabExpander;
import javax.swing.text.Utilities;
import javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView;

class SeparatedWrappedPlainView extends WrappedPlainView {
    
    private int _tabBase;
    private FontMetrics _metrics;
    
    private final Character wordSeparator;

    public SeparatedWrappedPlainView(Character wordSeparator, Element elem) {
        super(elem);
        assert(wordSeparator!=null);
        this.wordSeparator=wordSeparator;
    }


    /**
     * Rem: Copied from WrappedPlainView  only to be able to use our own 
     * getBreakLocation instead of the {@link Utilities#getBreakLocation} used by default
     */
    @Override
    protected int calculateBreakPosition(int p0, int p1) {
        Segment s = new Segment();
        try {
            getDocument().getText(p0, p1 - p0, s);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            assert false : "Couldn't load text";
        }
        int width = getWidth();
        int pos;
        pos = p0 + getBreakLocation(s, _metrics, _tabBase, _tabBase + width, this, p0);
        return pos;
    }

    /**
     * Rem: Copied from {@link Utilities#getBreakLocation} in order to
     * to break the text on our separator instead of on whitespaces.
     */
    private int getBreakLocation(Segment s, FontMetrics metrics, float x0, float x, TabExpander e, int startOffset) {
        char[] txt = s.array;
        int txtOffset = s.offset;
        int txtCount = s.count;
        int index = Utilities.getTabbedTextOffset(s, metrics, x0, x, e, startOffset, false); //, null, useFPIAPI);
        if (index >= txtCount - 1) {
            return txtCount;
        }
        for (int i = txtOffset + index; i >= txtOffset; i--) {
            char ch = txt[i];
            if (ch < 256) {
                // break on separator
                if (wordSeparator.equals(ch)) {
                    index = i - txtOffset + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                // a multibyte char found; use BreakIterator to find line break
                BreakIterator bit = BreakIterator.getLineInstance();
                bit.setText(s);
                int breakPos = bit.preceding(i + 1);
                if (breakPos > txtOffset) {
                    index = breakPos - txtOffset;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    void _updateMetrics() {
        Container component = getContainer();
        _metrics = component.getFontMetrics(component.getFont());
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, Shape a) {
        Rectangle r = a instanceof Rectangle ? (Rectangle) a : a.getBounds();
        _tabBase = r.x;
        _updateMetrics();
        super.paint(g, a);
    }

    @Override
    public float getPreferredSpan(int axis) {
        _updateMetrics();
        return super.getPreferredSpan(axis);
    }

    @Override
    public float getMaximumSpan(int axis) {
        _updateMetrics();
        return super.getMaximumSpan(axis);
    }

    @Override
    public float getMinimumSpan(int axis) {
        _updateMetrics();
        return super.getMinimumSpan(axis);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(float width, float height) {
        _updateMetrics();
        super.setSize(width, height);
    }
    
}
```